Weird error trying to uninstall python3
I have this issue in kubuntu 24.04
sudo apt remove python3
Reading package list... Done
Creating dependency tree... Done
Reading status information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that
you requested an impossible situation or, if you are using the
unstable distribution, that some required packages have not yet been built or
have been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
shim-signed : Depends: grub-efi-amd64-signed (>= 1.191~) but will not be installed or
grub-efi-arm64-signed (>= 1.191~) but is not installable or
base-files (< 12.3)
Depends: grub-efi-amd64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) but will not be installed or
grub-efi-arm64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) but is not installable
Depends: grub2-common (>= 2.04-1ubuntu24) but will not be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated hangs, this may be due to held packages.

System is updated and upgraded. Please, how can i fix that?

NEVER remove the default python version. It will destroy Ubuntu (in case you already removed python, your package manager may stop working and then you cannot even reinstall python). Instead, use virtual environment/miniforge, as outlined in https://askubuntu.com/a/1530295/124466
